# How to bulkify this code

Tags: apex, trigger, bulkification

The below code working and doing what is suppose to do but I know that the below code is not optimized/bulkify, how can I bulkfiy this code

```
public void SchedulingClass(List<Reading__c> reading) 
    {        
        for(Reading__c r : reading)
        {
            List<Reading__c> readings = [SELECT  Id, Name .... FROM Reading__c WHERE Id__c =: r.Id];

            if(readings.size() > 0)
            {
                List<Motor__c> motors = [SELECT Id,Name ... FROM Motor__c WHERE Id =: m.Id__c];

                If(motors.size() >0 )  
                {
                    List<Scheduling__c> sList = [SELECT Id, Name ...FROM Scheduling__c WHERE Id__c =: r.Id__c];                    
                    for(Scheduling__c pm : sList)
                    {                          
                      //
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A generous use of collections will help. The key is using the right Map Keys and properly creating the collections prior to use.

Now, you are missing some code on how you use them so there may be better ways to use them but given the limited code you provided this should get you started:

```
public void SchedulingClass(List<Reading__c> reading) 
    {        

        //Get a map of ID to reading records
        Map<ID,Reading__c> readings = New Map<ID,Reading__c>([Select ID, Name ... From Reading__c Where ID__c IN :reading]);

        //Get motors and map then to the ID of reading
        Map<ID,motor__c[]> readingToMotor = New Map<ID,Motor__c[]>();

        //This pattern could be put in a utility class using sObjects but thats another lesson    
        for(Motor__c m : [Select ID, Name, ... From Morot__c Where ID__c IN :readings.keySet]){
            Motor__c[] tmp = readingToMotor.get(m.ID__c);
            if(tmp == null)
                readingToMotor.put(m.ID__c,New Motor__c[]{m});
            else
                readingToMotor.get(m.ID__c).add(m);
        }

        //Get Schedule records mapped to the reading records
        Map<ID,Scheduling__c[]> readingToSchedule = New Map<ID,Scheduling__c[]>();

        for(Scheduling__c s : [Select ID, Name, ... From Scheduling__c Where ID__c IN :readings.keySet]){
            Scheduling__c[] tmp = readingToSchedule.get(s.ID__c);
            if(tmp == null)
                readingToSchedule.put(s.ID__c,New Scheduling__c[]{s});
            else
                readingToSchedule.get(s.ID__c).add(s);

            readingToSchedule.put(s.ID__c,s);
        }



        for(Reading__c r : readings.values())
        {            
                //Not sure why you had this here as you are not looping over them or using it anywhere but.....
                List<Motor__c> motors = readingToMotor.get(r.id);

                If(readingToMotor.containsKey(r.id))  
                {
                      if(readingToSchedule.containsKey(r.id){  
                         for(Scheduling__c pm : readingToSchedule.get(r.id))
                           {                          
                             //
                           }
                      }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting the error on very first line `Map<ID,Reading__c> readings = Map<ID,Reading__c([Select ID, Name From Reading__c Where ID__c IN :reading]);`  Error: Compile Error: Illegal assignment from List<Reading__c> to Map<Id,Reading__c>

Comment: I forgot a bracket. Basic debugging will be required as it was hacked together quickly

Comment: i have noticed and taken care of missing bracket but even after adding the missing bracket still getting the same error

Comment: I also forgot the new keyword

Comment: yes i have added new but the line of code is absolutely incorrect, you are creating Map<Id, object> but where is the Id you assigning and the object? your code of line does not make any sense to me unless you know something which I don't :)

Comment: Eric does know something you don't. The constructor for a Map can take a List<sObject> - when it creates the map, the id on the sObject becomes the map key and the object becomes the value. [SFDC Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor)